# how to replace a href link with image in transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, transition

i want to replace this href link with image, so i just want to make moving image instead of link, easily, replace "a href" with "img src" ,moving is triggered by "onclick" javascript, can you help me? if i do this, animation isnt working , so idk how to, heres Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/px7ezeka/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs-CZ">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Prace">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Web9.css">
    <title>Rostik</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="links">
        <a class="link" href="#">bullshit</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('.link').onclick = function () {
            var d = document.getElementById("links");
            d.className = d.className + " fly";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>


#links.fly {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 400px;
    transition: all 2s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: is it ok http://jsfiddle.net/px7ezeka/1/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want replace text to image when click on it :

**HTML**

```
<div id="links">
    <a class="link" href="#">bullshit</a>
    <img src="" class="hide image" />
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.querySelector('.link').onclick=function() {

            var d = document.getElementById("links");
            d.className = d.className + " fly";  
            $(".image").toggleClass("hide");
            $(".link").toggleClass("hide");
        }
```

**CSS**

```
#links.fly {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 400px;
    transition: all 2s ease-out;
}
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

It's hide your text and show image you want.

[Demo in FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/px7ezeka/6/)